# Distance between POINT and nearest LINESTING

Tags: sql-server, indexing, gis, distance

There are two MSSQL tables that contain spatial data: 
- AddressPoints - contains geolocation of addresses (POINT structure) 
- Pipeline - contains geolocation of pipeline (LINESTRING structure)

AddressPoints table should contain distance from nearest pipeline segment. I am currently trying to write efficient query. I ended up with following query:

```
select a.ogr_fid, min(a.geom.STDistance(p.geom))
from AddressPoints a, Pipeline p
group by a.ogr_fid
```

However, AddressPoints and Pipeline tables contain huge amount of data which affects execution speed.
Both tables contain spatial indexes, but I am not sure if this query utilizes them.

Comment: `MIN` suggests that you are looking for the nearest neighbor's distance, not all distances. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx) explains how to write a nearest neighbor query that uses spatial indexes. The requirements are rather strict

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have found acceptable solution:

```
select a.ogr_fid, min(a.geom.STDistance(p.geom))
from AddressPoint a
inner join Pipeline p on a.geom.STDistance(p.geom) < 200
group by a.ogr_fid
order by a.ogr_fid
```

This query does the same job as query from question. However it executes in 1 second. Execution time of first query is 47 seconds.